# Can Oracle be installed on Windows without being an administrator?

Tags: oracle, windows

Can the oracle software be installed on windows without having administrator privileges?

Comment: I ask because this was a top rated question on the Oracle Database proposal.

Comment: Does that make it a top rated question for this site tho? I'm gonna go with yes for right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that Oracle installation requires registry edits, service installations - I would say no.

Answer (score 7):

**No, but there are workarounds**

One workaround is to run a virtual machine that has Oracle and only Oracle installed. this has the significant benefit of insuring that the many kernel tweaks required of oracle are constrained within one instance.

Consider trying deployment within: [VMWare Thinapp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/), [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) (maybe), and I believe VirtualBox offers a user-land install, based on the documentation [here](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.0.0/UserManual.pdf).

Comment: It does in my experience on Windows 7